# Evaluate this indefinite inegral $\int \sin^{e}x \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate this  indefinite integral

> $$\int \sin^{e}x\, dx$$

*I evaluate from wolfram aplha but i didn't get it*
I have no idea from where I should start. Please give me hint.

Comment: Where did you find this question??

Comment: @Rohan one of my friend asked me today

Comment: @Rohan you have any idea or not how to can we solve it

Comment: Where did you come up with this monster?

Comment: @OriaGruber i usually solve calculus problems so my friends always asks me and i came up with this question and i have no idea so i pit it on stackexchange

Comment: I doubt if this can be expressed as an elementary function.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sorry i didnt get u

Comment: I meant that this integral is probably non-elementary similar to the integral $\int e^{x^{2}}\,dx$. But this is a guess and I have no proof for the same.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh suppose the limit of integration is from o to $\pi$ then how we will proceed

Comment: If you are seeking a definite integral then perhaps some numerical techniques (like Simpson's Rule) will help you get an approximate value.

Comment: Mathematica says: $\int \sin ^e(x) \, dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1+e}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(1+\frac{e}{2}\right)}-\cos (x) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-e}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right)$ for $0\leq x\leq \pi$

Answer (score 0):

The graph of this function can be computed from this  https://www.symbolab.com/graphing-calculator
My idea is first to find the area of each non-zero part in it and then take sum and see its convergence

Comment: We have to evaluate it without calculator or any graph caclulator etc

Comment: Ok if we consider $sin^{e}(x)=exp(e ln(sinx)$ then by considering 1 as a second function in integration by parts then I hope it may help you

Comment: not works u an also try

Answer (score 0):

The following is not a solution, it is just an idea. I'm not sure if it's the right path: 
$$I = \int \sin^{e}x\, dx$$

Apply the substitution 
$$u=\sin(x) \Leftrightarrow x = \arcsin(u)$$$$
du = \cos(x)dx = \cos(\arcsin(u))\,dx = \sqrt{1 - u^2}\,dx \implies dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}\, du$$
Also

$$I = \int \frac{u^e}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \, du $$
Multiply by the conjugate und we get
$$I = \int\frac{u^e\sqrt{1-u^2}}{1-u^2}\,du$$